# Unable to call Jquery function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I am new to *mvc* and *jquery*,

I have created one table with jquery and I am adding a button on each row. I need to call one function on the button click with argument.

My code is given bellow

```
function loadData(data) {

            var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
            var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
            thead.append('<th>Id</th><th></th>');
            thead.append('<th>Username</th>');

            tab.append(thead);
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {

                var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empID + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' +"" + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empName + '</td>');

 trow.append('<td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="Details(" ' + val.empID + ');" /></td>');


                tab.append(trow);
            });
            $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
            $("#AllEmployees").html(tab);

        };
```

and my function is:

```
        function Details(k) {

            alert("Failed! Please try again.");

        };
```

Here both functions are inside the document.ready method.

But the function call is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the details function outside  document ready.

```
function Details(k) {
     alert("Failed! Please try again.");
    }
```

Use this if you want to validate using your client side method.
Return true/false from your method.

```
trow.append('<td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="return Details(' + val.empID + ');"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra quote:

```
trow.append('<td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="Details(" ' + val.empID + ');" /></td>');
                                                                    ^
```

try this if your value `val.empID` is numeric:

```
trow.append('<td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="Details(' + val.empID + ');" /></td>')
```

If its a string then use `\` to escape single quote:

```
trow.append('<td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="Details(\'' + val.empID + '\');" /></td>')
```

Comment: thanks i got the answer by changing that code and also i placed my function outside document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

place the function outside document ready. Otherwise it will not be accessible from outside document ready. (your input will be rendered outside dom ready function)

Comment: thanks i got the answer by changing that code and also i placed my function outside document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     function loadData(data) {
        var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
        var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
        thead.append('<th>Id</th><th></th>');
        thead.append('<th>Username</th>');

        tab.append(thead);
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
            trow.append('<td>' + val.empID + '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +"" + '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' + val.empName + '</td>');
            var tabledata='<td><input type="button" value="Edit"/></td>'
            tabledata.attr("empID",val.empID);
            tabledata.click(Details)
            trow.append(tabledata);
            tab.append(trow);
        });
        $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
        $("#AllEmployees").html(tab);

    };

    function Details() {

        alert("Failed! Please try again."+this.attr("empID"));

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create an input like:

```
<input class="edit_button" type="button" value="Edit" />
```

And then in your document.ready

```
$('.edit_button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Failed! Please try again.");
});
```